# Is it possible to call a local variable from a function to another using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, time, function-pointers

For example if i was to make a complex calculation using several function where each function does a part of the job, is it possible for example to make the following:

```
void initialize_equations() {

    int t_constant;
    time_t times;
    double *current_time;
    times= time(NULL);

    t_constant = 365*24*60*60;


    *current_time =times/t_constant;

    printf("%Lf", current_time);
}

int year_day(time_t *crntT, int *constant) {

    int year, month;
    float year_l, month_l;

    year_l=(&current_time)/365; //trying to call crntT from previous function
    year=year_l+1970; //time starts at 1970 therefore turned it from float to int then summed time
    month=((year_l-year)*12)+1; // Month starts at Jan therefore +1

}
```

Comment: why not simply declare it as global variable?

Comment: @David declaring a global variable in code that is already a steaming pile will make it worse.

Comment: You don't "call" variables (unless they are function pointers, but let's not go there).  You "access" them. And no, you can't do that. Local variables only exist during the call to the function in which they're scoped.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access local variable declared in another function regardless it is a pointer or not in c. However, you can (but maybe you shall not) access memory allocated in another function as long as you have the address of this block of memory.

For instance, if you allocate memory for local variable 'current_time' (which you didn't, but this is another issue) by using:

```
double* current_time = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));
```

and you keep the address of allocated memory (the value hold in 'current_time'). Then, you can access the allocated memory in another function as long as you can somehow let that function know this address.

Having said that, why don't you just simply keep this value in a higher level place and then pass it into all functions that require this value?

Comment: so u mean i pass in the total seconds, and a reference to the year and day?

Comment: do know any source i can use to understand how to do that?